# Tight upper bound and sharp upper bound

Tags: upper-lower-bounds, mathematica

In koksma HLAWKA inequality
|Integration error|<= V(f) D*(x1...xn)
This result provides upper bound of integration error. I found some papers mentioned that bound is sharp and some of them saying it is tight even for very smooth function.
Does sharp bound means the same as tight bound ?

Comment: Welcome to Math.SE.  Please use MathJax. https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020